# Symfony Twig Form Theming of specific fields

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

I have a custom form field type and an associated form theme for it. On one page I have a lot of these fields, but one of the fields in particular I want to change.

Is there any way to theme certain fields of the same type (and in the same file) differently?

A simplified example:

form_fields.html.twig: (local theming file)

```
{% block my_dropdown_row %}
<div>
    {{ form_label(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

In my form template (all these fields have the same type - `my_dropdown`

```
{{ form_row(form.selectionA) }}
{{ form_row(form.selectionB) }}
{{ form_row(form.selectionC) }}
{{ form_row(form.final_selection) }}
```

How can I style the final field differently to the others? There is a lot of code in these widgets so less duplication the better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done. Here is how:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: I knew I had seen it somewhere! Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, as the linked page is quiet big, the answer should quote what is relevant for the question.

Comment: Well this is not something that can be explained with some quick comments, that is why i linked to the page where this is explained in full

Answer (score 1):

Old question and already answered, but would be nice to have more detailed info.

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

    {% block _product_name_widget %}
    <div class="text_widget">
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{{ form_widget(form.name) }}
```

Where block name `_product_name_widget` stands for

_ `form type(block prefix)`_ `form item name`_`render function`

http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field