# how to customize the style of the form made from twig on Symfony?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

hello I was wondering how to customize the form on symfony instead of having already a ready-made template (especially the bootstrap one).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony Twig Form Theming of specific fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297818/symfony-twig-form-theming-of-specific-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Hello here is the solution to this problem :

To start, here is the place where you can change the theme of the forms to Symfony:

```
// project_name/config/packages/twig.yaml

twig :

     ... 


     form_themes: ['bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig']
```

if you want to see the default packages that are available you have to go to the following folder  :

```
 project_name/vendor/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form
```

Now you can notice that twig file names match the style that you can add for your forms made with twig

so now if you really want to make your own style of form just create a twig file in that same folder `'project_name/vendor/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form'` and then replace that filename with `'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig'` in  `'project_name/config/packages/twig.yaml'`